# PHP MySQL - get comment count for all posts written by one user

Tags: php, mysql, join

My aim is to get a total count of 'pending' and 'approved' comments for all posts for a specific user. The comments table has a status column for 'pending' or 'approved'. For the record, the page_id in the comments table maps to the id in the posts table.

I started writing the statement below - but I think I have it back to front:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts JOIN comments on posts.id = comments.page_id WHERE author = posts.author';
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $results = $stmt->fetch();
```

To give visibility to the table structures, below are the table columns.

Comments table
[image: comments table]

Posts table
[image: posts table]

Users table
[image: users table]

I have a foreign key the relates the users `id` to the posts `user_id`.

I'm going to continue to try to do this - but - would like some guidance on how to achieve make this work.

Edit:

I have an admin panel for users.  I want to create a table of approved comments with the approved comment count at the top, and a table of pending comments with the pending comment count at the top.  In each table will be a button to either approve or unapprove comments - but only for their posts.  Here's an image of how I have done this for all comments.

[image: example usage]

Comment: Are you after separate counts each for `pending` and `approved` or just a combined total?

Comment: Great question - separate counts for pending and approved.

Comment: It would be great if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63443537/edit) to show some examples of the results you want

Comment: I know I've already answered this but that was before your example result. Since you're fetching a list of all the comments anyway, can't you just do two queries (for each different `status`) and use `$stmt->rowCount` for your table headers?

Comment: The example I gave is all comments for all posts.  For instance for the approved comment count here's the function I use:

`function getApprovedCommentCount(){
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE status = "Approved"');
    $stmt->execute();
    $adminCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $ApprovedCommentCount;
}`
Since the comments don't relate to a user I got confused trying to work out how to get the counts per user.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah yep, that makes perfect sense. Good luck with the rest of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a pretty straight-forward query using `SUM` and `CASE`

```sql
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS approvedCount,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS pendingCount
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN posts p
  ON c.page_id = p.id
WHERE p.user_id = :user_id
```

The main thing this query does is adds up all the `comments` rows with `status = 'approved'` and another where `status = 'pending'` as two separate counts.

The `COALESCE` functions are there to cater for when there are no matching records for the `user_id` you're looking for. If they were not used, the result would be `null` instead of `0`.

Comment: Wow - I've not seen a query like this before.  Any chance you can help me understand what this is doing?  For instance. c.status - how does that get read when the table is comments? I'm excited to learn more about this.

Comment: @SteveShead notice I've aliased `comments` as `c` (and `posts` as `p`)

Comment: Ah - that makes sense - didn't know you could do that - awesome.  I'm looking forward to the day when this becomes straight forward for me! :) ...so, to make this work I would need to echo 'approvedCount' for a specific user_id, right?

Comment: This gives you both `approvedCount` and `pendingCount` for any given `user_id` in one query.

Comment: Thought you'd like to know that it works like a charm.  From this I should be able to write the query to list them per my example.  I learned a lot from this - thanks for your help.

Comment: And used the premise of your answer to solve the second part.  Here's the query:
`SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN posts p ON comments.page_id = p.id WHERE status = "Pending" AND p.user_id ='.$_SESSION['id'].''` - correlates to the number of pending and approved found in the answer you gave.  Again - really appreciate the assist - learned a ton here!

Comment: Don't do that, use a prepared statement instead with parameter binding. If you're not sure what that means, search for it. There are a lot of articles explaining what it is and why you should use it

Comment: Good point - I've been using prepared statements and should have caught that - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the problem where you populate each page, you're retrieved ID from POSTS and ID from COMMENTS by using a "SELECT * FROM" over an inner join containing both tables. In that context, columns from POSTS and COMMENTS with the same name (id, img) will be returned and the result will be ambiguous, i.e. in your PHP code when you ask for $row->id, will it be POSTS.ID or COMMENTS.ID?

You need COMMENTS.ID to update the status in COMMENTS. You could just rename "COMMENTS.ID as COMMENT_ID", or select only from COMMENTS knowing the "ID" you get back is going to be COMMENT.ID

Since you only want rows from COMMENTS in the result, I would only select from COMMENTS and use a subquery to constrain it by POSTS instead of a join, and also further limiting the SELECT to the list of columns you explicitly need for your result so you don't have to pay for returning columns you don't need, e.g.

```
SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, C.CONTENT, C.VOTES C.STATUS /* but you know that STATUS already, heheh */
FROM COMMENTS C WHERE 
  C.STATUS = :STATUS AND
  C.PAGE_ID IN ( SELECT P.ID FROM POSTS P WHERE P.USER_ID = :USER )
```

**Helpful indices:**

- COMMENTS on STATUS, PAGE_ID
- POSTS on USER_ID

**Assumptions:**

- COMMENTS.PAGE_ID --> POSTS.ID Foreign key dependency.
- POSTS.ID and COMMENTS.ID are unique.
- You're not going to get back so many rows that you need to paginate...a different approach is needed for a limit query.

Comment: Thanks John - that looks like another great way to achieve this - I appreciate the reply.